# Update an Existing Outlook Appointment

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

Having created an outlook appointment doing something like this;

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = null;

 app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

 appt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
 appt.Subject = sub;
 appt.Body = body;
 appt.Location = Loc;
 appt.Recipients.Add(email);
 appt.Save();
 appt.Send();

 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = appt.ForwardAsVcal();
 mailItem.To = email;
 mailItem.Body = body;
 mailItem.Send();
```

Looking for pointers, as I'm having difficulty finding a definitive answer via Google.

How do I then (at a later date..) retrieve this appointment again from one or more outlook accounts and update some details?

Or is it possible to release a new appointment that will overwrite the existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always accessing the appointment from the same mailbox, store the value of the AppointmentItem.EntryID property and reopen it at a later point using Namespace.GetItemfromID.

If you need to access the appointment from multiple mailboxes, read the value of the AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID. Unfortunately Outlook Object Model would not let you search on a binary property (MAPIFolder.Items.Find). You would need to either drop down to the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi) or use Redemption - see
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/63ea7bda-9767-4145-8ced-78e1095a49f8/